# Origin of the phrase, "I got to talking to..."?

Tags: phrases

Where does it come from?  Is it universal or specific to a particular region?

Comment: It's a variant of _I got talking to ..._, which is another way of saying _I started talking to ..._, which is another way of saying _I was talking to ..._ They're all phrases that can introduce a report on a conversation, usually as an introduction to something else.

Answer (score 1):

The word get (past tense got) can mean begin, especially coupled with to. [See here](http://i.word.com/idictionary/get).

> get to it
>   get moving

The reversal of *to get* into *get to* tends to be an informal usage (when used in this way).

I believe it to be an extension of the concept of get as meaning *to reach (a state of)*.  This is a very old usage of the word dating back to *geta* ca. 1200 in Old Norse.